# How can I get GA utm parameters in a secondary page in user's session

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, universal-analytics

I am using GA universal analytics. I want to get the `utm_content` parameter of the user, that had come to my page with some. But I want it to get it in any page user visit in that session.

I just thought about reading cookie, but the data is hashed and I understood that Google did not want that way. [Some analysis on cookie](http://www.cheatography.com/jay-taylor/cheat-sheets/google-analytics-utm-parameters-v2/)

can I do it by any API method in Analytics.js or with any other solution?

Comment: Campaign parameters apply to the session, not just the landing page. There is no need to muck about with cookies (which would not work with Universal Analytics in any case).

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be able to get use the tracker and call the [get](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/method-reference#get) method.
It returns the value currently associated with the given field. This should be called on an instantiated tracker object.

```
ga(function(tracker) {
  car content = ga('get', 'campaignContent', 'content');
});
```

This function will execute once the analytics.js library has loaded. When the function executes, the tracker parameter will have a reference to the default tracker (assuming it was created prior to the function being called). The tracker reference is then used to get the [campaignContent](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#campaignContent) value.